# How to set active APN on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, apn

`Android 4`: Under `Mobile Network Settings` I have `Access Point Names` menu, which lists 4 APNs, first one's got a radio button selected next to it.

I'm trying to select one of the other `APNs` - which takes me to edit mode for that `APN`, however there doesn't seem to be a way to select an active one (as in - put a radio button selected next to it).

Long tap and menu options don't provide that ability either.

Comment: Your provider might offer different APNs for different things -- but you can only select between those for "internet access". As you ddidn't give closer information, I cannot tell about yours -- but I have e.g. an APN for MMS which has no radio-button next to it (as it's only for the messaging service). So I assume there might be other "specific ones" as well.

Comment: exactly, there are several APNs - one for pay monthly customers, one for Pay As You Go (I'm on O2 UK) and some MMS ones, the one I need is PAYG APN, which happens to be second in the list - but my question is how to get it selected? the UI behaviour is counter intuitive.

Comment: You could check with your provider which APNs are obsolete for you, and simply remove those. Maybe one could tell more if you could include a screenshot with your question.